# TFS 2018 Upgrade Build Agent

Tags: tfs-2018

I am testing a TFS 2015 to TFS 2018 upgrade.  My environment includes one database server, one TFS app server, and one TFS build server.   I was able to upgrade the app tier without any issues.   It's been awhile since I've done this, but I assume I just run the TFS upgrade installer again on the build server and it will give me the option to update the build agent?   I didn't see anything for it when I ran the upgrade on the app server.

Comment: Are you talking about XAML builds or JSON (aka "classic") builds?

Comment: I am not sure what our developers were using, but if I were to guess it would be the classic builds since we were pretty much out of the box with minimal to no customizations.    I'm on the implementation side and trying to determine how the build server gets upgraded.  I recall in previous versions there was a 'Build Service Configuration Wizard', but there doesn't seem to be that option with the 2018 installer.

Comment: This is a critical piece of information. TFS 2015 introduced a new build system, but supported older-style XAML builds. XAML builds had a build controller/build agent setup that involved using a configuration wizard. The JSON build system deprecated XAML builds in favor of a simplified setup. The best place for you to start is with the official Microsoft documentation.

Comment: I have confirmed that we are using XAML builds in 2015.   I'll check the documentation to see what else I can come up with.  THanks.